# First anchored link after page load requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

The page I'm designing has a fixed position bar at the bottom for references, which starts on page load with a height of zero, but can be expanded up via clicking a div positioned directly on top of it. As well, the individual references are anchors to links up in the content block, and I'm using the scrollTo and localScroll jQuery plugins for navigation - if an anchored link is clicked while the reference bar is expanded, it will localScroll to it, if the bar is reduced, it will scroll to it, then call the expansion animation. The first part of the script handling all of this works great - the reference bar opens on a click to the positioned div just fine - but the first anchored link clicked after page load, whether the reference bar is closed or open, requires two clicks, not one, to do anything. Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reftag").css('bottom', '0px');
    $("#refblock").css('height','opx');
    $("refblock").scrollTo($("#refblock h4"),0);


    $("#reftag").click(
        function(){
            var offset = $("#refblock").offset();
            if(($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height() - offset.top) > 100)
            {
                $("#reftag").animate({bottom: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
                $("#refblock").animate({height:"0px"},{queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
                $("#refblock").scrollTo($("#refblock h4"),0);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#reftag").animate({bottom: "200px"}, {queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
                $("#refblock").animate({height:"200px"},{queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
            }
            return false;
        });

    $("a.ref").click(
        function () {           
            var offset = $("#refblock").offset();
            if(($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height() - offset.top) > 100)
            {
                $('#textblock').localScroll({target:'#refblock'});
            }
        else{
            $('#textblock').localScroll({target:'#refblock',onAfter:function(){
                $("#reftag").animate({bottom: "200px"}, {queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
                $("#refblock").animate({height:"200px"}, {queue:false, duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
            }});    
            }
                return false;
        });
    });
```

And here's the CSS for the refblock (in case it's of any value):

```
#refblock{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 0px;
    background: rgb(194,1,92);
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Any ideas? Is it a problem with the script, or something else? I'll post a link to the site when it goes live, if there's anything else that'd be useful for an answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent default action triggered by click on `a.ref` link:

```
$("a.ref").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular place in the code where this needs to go? I altered the function (placing the e.preventDefault() first inside the curly brackets) and I got the same result.